# Валидация сайта (проверка на ошибки в разметке)

Tags: html

Добрый день, при проверке шаблона сайта при помощи [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/) столкнулся с ошибками, которые не понимаю, как решить:

> `Line 168, Column 81: end tag for "img" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified ... c="./images/ledit.png" alt="LEDIL"></a><em>LEDIL лидер в области инноваций све ... You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">".
> Info Line 168, Column 36: start tag was here
> <span class="tooltip"><a href=""><img src="./images/ledit.png" alt="LEDIL"></...`

Вот фрагмент кода:

```
<div id="logotips">
    <span class="tooltip"><a href=""><img src="./images/ledit.png"         alt="LEDIL"></a><em>text
                                                                                       <i></i></em></span>
</div>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<img src="" alt="" />` так же для `<br />`, `<hr />`

А вообще лучше не морочить себе этим голову!

Comment: чего не морочить, иногда валидатор указывает на откровенные ошибки, которые можно машинально не заметить. Rumato, лучше установить плагин для браузера, который сразу будет сообщать о появившихся ошибках еще в процессе верстки

Comment: спасибо за помошь, разобрался)))

Comment: @makregistr речь шла конкретно о HTML и XHTML относительно DOCTYPE